# Showing existence of a vector $v$ such that $\|Av\|=\|v\|$ given two eigenvalues of the linear transformation $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Let $A : \mathbb R ^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^ 2$ be a linear transformation with eigenvalues $\frac{2}{3}$
and $\frac{9}{5}$.

Then, show that there exists a non-zero
vector $v \in \mathbb  R^ 2$ such that $\|Av\|=\|v\|$.

My try:

$\exists v_1 ,v_2$ (non-zero) such that $Av_1=\frac{2}{3}v_1$ and $Av_2=\frac{9}{5}v_2$

Will I have to construct some vector $v$ using $v_1,v_2$ such that $\|Av\|=\|v\|$?
I am not so sure. But I could not construct such a vector yet.

Any help?

Comment: Try to look at the diagnoalize form of the matrix.

Comment: @eranreches this would not help to build such a vector explicitly, because we don't know the angle between the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let the eigenvectors be $v_1$ and $v_2$ as you described.

Define an application $\Bbb S^1\to \Bbb R$ by 
$$f(a,b)=\frac{\|A(av_1+bv_2)\|}{\|av_1+bv_2\|}.$$
This is a continuous function defined on a compact, hence it takes all possible values between its $\inf$ and $\sup$.

We know that $f(1,0) = \frac 23$ and $f(0,1)=\frac 95$, therefore $\sup f\ge \frac 95$ and $\inf f\le \frac 23$ hence there exists a point $(a,b)$ on $\Bbb S^1$ such that $f(a,b)=1$, which gives you the desired result.

Comment: great just loved it

Comment: How to show that there is no non-zero vector $v$ such that $||Av||>2||v||$? Also, no non-zero vector $v$ with $||Av||<\frac12||v||$?

Comment: @Silent for the first question, you can not. Just study $A=\begin{pmatrix}9/5 & k\\ 0& 2/3\end{pmatrix}$ for sufficiently large $k$. Neither you can for the second question: take $k=-9/5$ and a vector $v=(1,1)^T$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Consider the function $$f: v \mapsto ||Av|| - ||v||$$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a path $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ from $v_1$ to $v_2$.

Note that, as stated, you need not actually construct a vector $v$ for which $||Av|| = ||v||$, only show that such a vector exists.

**Remark** More generally, using the same idea one can show that given any linear transformation $B: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, say, $|\lambda_1| \leq |\lambda_2|$, and any $\mu \in [\lambda_1, \lambda_2]$, there is a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $||A v|| = \mu ||v||$ (where $||v||$ is the usual norm, say).

Comment: Can we use your remark for this: there is no non-zero vector $v$ such that $||Av||>2||v||$? Also, no non-zero vector $v$ with $||Av||<\frac12||v||$?

Comment: @Silent Using the same ideas as in the remark, yes, we can show that those claims are true for the particular $A$ in the question statement.

Comment: @TravisWillse Are you sure about that?   Your idea works when $\mu \in [\lambda_1,\lambda_2] $, but outside this interval you have no info.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy You're right---I had imagined that OP's $A$ was just $D := \operatorname{diag}\left(\frac{2}{3}, \frac{9}{5}\right)$ (or otherwise had orthogonal eigenspaces), but that was not the case. Without that restriction we could have, e.g., $A = P D P^{-1}$, where $P = \pmatrix{1&a\\ \cdot&1}$, and $||A v||$ can achieve a value $$\left(\frac{17}{15} |a| + O(a^{-1})\right) |v| ,$$ which we can make arbitrarily large.