# A question based on linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with its 2 eigenvalues given

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

This question was asked in my linear algebra quiz and i am unable to solve it .

> Let $A: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a linear transformation with eigenvalues $2/3$ and $9/5$ . Then , show that there doesnot exists vector $v $ such that

1. $\|Av\|>2\|v\|,$
2. $\|Av\|<\frac{1}{2}\|v\| $.

Also note that a question with similar statement was asked before here:

[Showing existence of a vector $v$ such that $\|Av\|=\|v\|$ given two eigenvalues of the linear transformation $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225337/showing-existence-of-a-vector-v-such-that-av-v-given-two-eigenvalues)

But that is about proving $\|Av\| =\|v\| $ not what I was asked to prove in quiz and also User :Silent asked my question  in comment but it was not answered as one user said it cant be proved and another didnot replied.

Kindly shed some light on it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments that you referred to have already spelled out how to construct counterexamples to both these statements. For (i), take
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{9}{5} & 2\\
0 & \frac{2}{3}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
v = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then $\lVert v\rVert = 1$, but $\lVert A v\rVert = \sqrt{2^2+(2/3)^2} > 2$.

For (ii), take
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{9}{5} & -\frac{9}{5}\\
0 & \frac{2}{3}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
v = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then $\lVert v\rVert = \sqrt{2}$, but $\lVert A v\rVert = 2/3 < \sqrt{2}/2$.